# Group columns based on value and then concatenate to a single value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I saw plenty of forums in here that did not work for my situation. I have

```
Col_1,   Col_2,    Col_3,   Col_n
TRUE     FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
FALSE    TRUE      TRUE     FALSE
TRUE     FALSE     FALSE    TRUE
```

I need to create a select statement that returns a new column with the following results:

```
New_Column
Col_1
Col_2, Col_3
Col_1, Col_n
```

In other words, if the column is `True` then add the **column name** to my new column. So my result set will look like:

```
myID, myName, myDesc, Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_n, New_Column
```

I tried:

```
SELECT
  myID,
  myName,
  myDesc,
  ((CASE WHEN col_1 = 'TRUE' THEN 'col_1' END) + ', ' + (CASE WHEN col_2 = 'TRUE' THEN 'col_2' END) + ', ' + (CASE WHEN col_3 = 'TRUE' THEN 'col_3' END) + ', ' + (CASE WHEN col_n = 'TRUE' THEN 'col_n' END) ) as  New_Column
FROM myTable
```

But the result set was incorrect. How can I get the result set I need with the design given to me?

When I say that the results are incorrect I mean the following:

```
myID, myName, myDesc, Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_n, New_Column

Data, Data, TRUE, False, false, true, Null

Data, Data, false, Col_2, Col_3, false, Null

Data, Data, Col_1, Null, Null, Col_n, Col_1Col_2Col_3Col_n
```

This is what I expect:

```
myID, myName, myDesc, Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_n, New_Column

Data, data, Col_1, Col_2, NULL, Col_N, Col_1Col_2Col_N
```

Comment: … well, for starters, she's going to get a bunch more commas than she'd probably like, since those aren't conditional … In MySQL, `group_concat` would work, but I don't think that works on MS-SQL Server.

Comment: it returns value, value, True, true, False, NULL for some records. For other records it shows value, value, Col_1, Null, Col_3, Null, Null and in this situation it should be value, value, Col_1, Null, Col_3, Null, Col_1 and Col_3 for the New_Column. Sometimes it returns value, value, col_1, col_2, null, null, (col_1,col_2,col_3,col_n)

Comment: If you're going to down-vote... please also vote to close or explain why. This might be a task resulting from a horrid requirement, but it is a very particular (and not very easy) task that has been asked in a clear manner (after trying something).

Comment: Thank you very much pst - I really though I was clear enough and I did the research but I can provide more details if necessary. The problem with this thing is that it doesn't allow you for much formatting making it time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting a NULL result because each of your CASE clauses will return a NULL when a column is FALSE.  You should be doing something like:

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE MyTable (col_1 VARCHAR(5),
                        col_2 VARCHAR(5),
                        col_3 VARCHAR (5),
                        col_n VARCHAR(5)
                        )
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'                       
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE'                        


SELECT  STUFF(( CASE WHEN col_1 = 'TRUE' THEN ',col_1'
                     ELSE ''
                END ) + ( CASE WHEN col_2 = 'TRUE' THEN ',col_2'
                               ELSE ''
                          END ) + ( CASE WHEN col_3 = 'TRUE' THEN ',col_3'
                                         ELSE ''
                                    END )
              + ( CASE WHEN col_n = 'TRUE' THEN ',col_n'
                       ELSE ''
                  END ), 1, 1, '') AS New_Column
FROM    myTable 

ROLLBACK
```